# What is the best way to perform record changes on post in Django?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am pretty new to python, my backend experience consists of Java only and to be honest I am really shocked with how handy python can be, especially DRF. I am using Django rest framework in the project, but it is getting bigger and I have to provide more robust api's.

There is a functionality that inserts a record, and for that I use DRF. Now I am going to introduce another functionality that inserts one record but I have to increment some value in other records after the insertion, can DRF handle this too?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could override the `create` method if you are using a view that subclasses [CreateModelMixin](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createmodelmixin) and insert the record after the call to `super()`

Comment: If the value/instance should always be inserted whenever an instance of the created model is created then you could use a [`post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the create action method in your Post views, once you insert a new record successfully, you update another model instance manually.

```
def create(self, request, pk=None):
    with transaction.atomic():
        # pass
        return Response({
            'message': 'ok'
        })
```

2. Using `receiver`, register a receiver for your post model, once it detects there is a new insertion, you can do anything you want:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=ColumnArticle)
def article_receiver(sender, instance: ColumnArticle = None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created: # once create
        # do something over here
```